# Do DELETE queries take the same amount of time as SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, sql-delete

I am hoping to delete all the duplicates in my large DB.
I wrote a query which first filters about 200k records out of a million records and then SELECTs the records.

Now, this whole process takes about 10 MINS 30 SECS under a certain system load. Now, if I replaced the `SELECT` command with `DELETE`, will it take the same amount of time?

I cannot test it myself because I do not have DELETE privileges right at this moment.

My Queries are as follows:

1. For Select

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
    ID,
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME,
    AGE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY
            ID,
            FIRSTNAME,
            LASTNAME,
            AGE
            ORDER BY
                ID,
                FIRSTNAME,
                LASTNAME,
                AGE
    ) AS row_num
    FROM 
        NEWTABLE
    
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE row_num > 1;
```

2. For Delete

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
    ID,
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME,
    AGE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY
            ID,
            FIRSTNAME,
            LASTNAME,
            AGE
            ORDER BY
                ID,
                FIRSTNAME,
                LASTNAME,
                AGE
    ) AS row_num
    FROM 
        NEWTABLE
    
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE row_num > 1;
```

Comment: I'd really suggest setting this up in a controlled environment where you could test it safely as much as you want. You'll have your numbers then.

Comment: There is more overhead with the delete as the transaction log is updated with each delete and eventually the data table. I would use the SQL Profiler and see first hand how they perform. Measure, measure, and measure again

Comment: Is there anyway I could reduce the time taken? Maybe a different approach for writing this query perhaps? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A couple of thoughts: Delete will take longer as it needs to write to disk.  10 minutes is a really long time to hold the locks that the DB will take.  There seems  to be no reason (in the SQL given) to use `PARTITION BY` - it's great for aggregate functions, and there aren't any, so if you can, remove that.  Finally: look at using an SQL Temporary Table.  Populate the temporary table with the ID, then do the delete based on the temporary table. That may reduce the time that's required for the locks to be held, depending on how have to design your transaction management.

Comment: @GregHNZ When I remove the partition, I am not able to return all the records. I can only return the first one :( Could you please help me with the query itself?

Comment: It looks like you hope to remove duplicate rows from your table.  If you [edit] your question to explain what you hope to do, it will help us help you. Your method seems to be a heavyweight way to deduplicate.

Comment: @O.Jones Yes, I am trying to delete the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, if I replaced the SELECT command with DELETE, will it take the same amount of time?

No, almost certainly not.

`delete` is a data modification and fully logged operation, neither of which `select` is.

The `delete` will need to acquire `IX` then `X` locks in order to delete rows, which may be blocked by other concurrent processes, depending on database usage.

The `delete` will need to update the base table and also any relevant indexes, plus write the modifications to the transaction log.

Depending on the performance of your hardware and IO it may be better to delete rows in *batches* of no more than approximately 5000, which is the threshold for the number of *locks*; this should prevent SQL Server escalating row locks to a table lock which would aid concurrency. You can add a `top` clause in your CTE to accomplish this.

Also, your CTE doesn't need to select all columns, the `Id` should suffice.

It may be worth experimenting with using a `view` in line with [this advice](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/04/how-to-delete-just-some-rows-from-a-really-big-table/).